# ORM - Mixing hibernate with in-memory data

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have two java classes, A & B, with A holding a reference to B:

```
public class A {
   private long id;
   private B b;
   ...
}

public class B {
   private long id;
   ...
}
```

In my database only instances of A are stored, alongside with the ID of the referenced B's:

```
$ select * from tableA;
id  | bid | ...
---------------
1   | 42  |
2   | 42  |
3   | 43  |
...
```

However, B are *not* stored in the database, but accessible through some implementation of a service layer ServiceB:

```
public interface ServiceB {
   public B getB(long bid);
}
```

How can I model that using Hibernate? I'd preferably use an XML-based HBM configuration. I also would like to avoid adding a transient field in A holding bid (if it is possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting here the solution found for reference.

You have to create a custom hibernate `UserType` which is used on the mapping for the `bid` field in `A` class. Implementing `UserType` is already well explained on Internet and is not the point here. Suffice to say that the `nullSafeGet()` operation convert the database id to a B instance by loading the corresponding B from the service layer; and the `nullSafeSet()`, the other way around, convert a B instance to it's internal id to store to the database.

Linking this custom user type to the service layer can be done several ways depending on the injection framework used (Guice, Spring, custom solution...) but should not be a problem.

You need a custom `UserType` for each referenced class `B`. Using generics may be useful in the case of several referenced classes deriving from a common base class, it's left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a `Repository` and build a new Object based on A & B.
The `Repository` uses Hibernate to retriebv `A` and the Service to retrieve `B`.

Comment: I'd like to avoid this, as I have many _real_ A and do not want to introduce a new extra-layer on top of all of them. Also I do not see how I can map B id to B w/o having to add an extra field `A.bid`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to develop a new org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister.  This is essentially what Hibernate OGM (Hibernate+JPA using NoSQL backings) does, if you need a reference on how to accomplish that.  You'd continue to use the standard persisters for the relational entities, and use your custom one for the non-relational one(s).